# Is it possible to be more page/post specific with admin_enqueue_script?

Tags: functions, css, hooks, admin-css

I am using this code to load a stylesheet in the admin, but only on post.php related pages:

```
function my_enqueue_for_post_pages_only($hook) {
    if( 'post.php' != $hook )
        return;
    wp_register_style( 'custom_wp_admin_css_for_post_pages_only', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style_admin-post.css', false, '1.0.0' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'custom_wp_admin_css_for_post_pages_only' );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue_for_post_pages_only' );
```

But I am needing to be more specific with where this stylesheet loads...**I would like to enqueue it only on 3 post.php edits screens:**

- post.php?post=7&action=edit
- post.php?post=10&action=edit
- post.php?post=18&action=edit

**Changing line 2 to this does not work:**

```
if( 'post.php?post=7&action=edit' != $hook )
```

Is it even possible to be this specific with the [admin_enqueue_scripts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts) hook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$hook_suffix` global (copy of which you are getting passed to the hook) doesn't go into such detail.

However there is plenty more of context to check. In modern WP versions bulk of it is via [`get_current_screen()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_current_screen/) which returns [`WP_Screen`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Screen) object with plenty of stuff (in this case you would want to check `id` and `post_type` properties likely).

As for post's ID — [`get_the_ID()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_the_id/) should work perfectly fine in that context.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I had actually been looking in to get_current_screen along with admin_enqueue_script, but all the examples and articles for get_current_screen were very confusing (I am a PHP novice). I have asked another question, regarding get_current_screen, perhaps you could help there too?: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/159476/simple-basic-use-of-get-current-screen