# Simple/basic use of get_current_screen

Tags: functions, css, admin-css

I would like to load a stylesheet on only 3 admin pages:

- post.php?post=7&action=edit
- post.php?post=10&action=edit
- post.php?post=18&action=edit

I was trying with [`admin_enqueue_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts) but it doesn't seem to be capable of such specificity ([see my related wpse post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/159471/is-it-possible-to-be-more-page-post-specific-with-admin-enqueue-script)), which led me to [`get_current_screen`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_screen). But all the examples and articles I find about [`get_current_screen`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_screen) refer to using it with a plugin and/or plugin options page:

- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_screen#Example
- http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-conditionally-including-js-and-css-with-get_current_screen--wp-25378
- http://amme86.wordpress.com/2013/12/10/25/

**I would simply like to use [`get_current_screen`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_screen) in my functions.php to determine if the admin page loaded is 1 of the 3 pages and if so load a css file.**

A simple example would be very helpful (php novice here). Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this but theoretically you could do something like this (Using the Codex as an Example):

```
function load_custom_wp_admin_style() {
    $pageArr = array(1, 2, 3);
    if(isset($_GET['post']) && in_array($_GET['post'], $pageArr)){
        wp_register_style( 'custom_wp_admin_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/admin-style.css', false, '1.0.0' );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'custom_wp_admin_css' );
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'load_custom_wp_admin_style' );
```

We get the current screen and set the page IDs we would like to include any scripts or styles. We then make sure that there is a `$_GET['post']` set which holds our post->ID and we also want to make sure we're in the correct post type (though you could probably skip the whole current screen thing entirely and just use `$_GET`). We then check to see if the current post ID is in our array of accepted IDs and if so: enqueue.

Comment: Tried it. Seems to work perfectly! Thank you so much. Could I trouble you for an example without "the whole current screen thing" as you mentioned, just using $_GET?

Comment: @codeview Glad to hear it! I've updated my answer and removed the references to `get_current_screen()`. If this works, don't forget to click the checkmark to show others that the question has been answered!

Comment: That works too! This is very helpful. If I don't need to use get_current_screen I will use your edited code but I have copied the pre-edit for reference since you removed it.